# How is libvmod-memcached useful?

Tags: caching, memcached, varnish

https://www.varnish-cache.org/vmod/memcached

I have seen this vmod on the varnish-cache site.

My question is how can this mod be useful? I thought that varnish was high performance because it stored the cached objects in memory. Is there a particular use case where using memcached with varnish would enhance frontend performance?

As mentioned below, the site mentions what the memcached module would do but not a specific use case..

> This VMOD provides a general purpose memcached client module for
>   Varnish using libmemcached to access memcached servers. It implements
>   the basic memcached operations of get, set, incr, decr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memcached vmod is useful for storing administrative data across multiple Varnish servers.

One common example is metering quota on newspaper sites, where you have multiple Varnish servers but a single quota of n articles per day.

In essence you always have to write some sort of logic in VCL for it to be useful.